# cuDNN isn't found FWD algo for convolution. How to TRAIN DARKNET ON GE FORCE GTX 1650

Tags: training, gpu

[image]

ISSUE: while training Darknet with GE FORCE GTX 1650 using following:
CUDA 11.0
cuDNN 8.0.5
OPENCV 4.5

Model starts training with config file details as below for [net] section:

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.949
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000
policy=steps
steps=4800,5400
scales=.1,.1

#cutmix=1
mosaic=1

#:104x104 54:52x52 85:26x26 104:13x13 for 416
```

When I change the batch from 64 to 32 (reducing it ) coupled with subdivisions increased from 16 to as high as 128, it keeps on going well but then stops after some time as reported above:

```
 Error: cuDNN isn't found FWD algo for convolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the cfg file subdivision. I think it is due to RAM problem as stated by others and i change it from 16 to 64 while maintaining the batch size at 64 and it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).